# Unity gain op-amp buffer, single supply - potential problems?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I need to precision buffer a DC (or slow changing) voltage of around 2.5V using an opamp in non-inverting unity gain mode and driven from a single supply using no resistors. Supply voltage is 5V. Is it enough just to wire it as described? Opamp chosen is [OPA2188](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2188.pdf).

Potential problems I can see are PSU noise being introduced, which may mean special power supply decoupling. Any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common mode voltage range could be an issue:

[image]

With power supply at 5V you are left with a max common mode voltage of 3.5V. In non-inverting configuration the inverting input will sit at about 2.5V so you only have 1V headroom. If your supply lowers just a bit you risk malfunctioning. And even if it stays stiff at 5V, note that those specs are given with an \$R_L=10k\Omega\$ (see above the table). So if you use the opamp as a buffer your load could have lower resistance and this could impact the max common mode voltage tolerated by the opamp.

Comment: Thanks - good point. I will probably change it to ADA4528-2

Comment: RE: "it is not stated with which accuracy that (V+)-1.5V is guarenteed, nor the manufacturing spread is specified". The value given is a maximum, not a typical. From a vendor like TI, it should be trustworthy. Likely a typical part would work with a slightly higher input CM voltage, and the value given is intended to account for manufacturing variation. From a company like TI, this should be a 6-sigma limit, meaning no more than about 1 in a billion parts should fail the spec.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for the useful information, especially the 6&sigma; threshold (BTW, is there some industrial standard, or some other document where these info are collected, or is it common practitioners' knowledge?). So I stand corrected for that part. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The 6-sigma number is part of "Six Sigma" quality management. It's not necessarily a promise to customers but something they should do to avoid waste, returns and unhappy customers. Correction: note in the [wiki article on Six Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) that 1 ppb defect rate is actually overly optimisitic.

Comment: FYI, I found [this document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/szzq076g/szzq076g.pdf) which says "TI manufacturing uses process capability measurements as a key component of process monitoring and control with a
goal to achieve values of Cp > 2.00 and Cpk > 1.67." Wiki article on [process capability index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_capability_index) tells how this relates to test margins.

Comment: And Cp > 2.0 does imply the spec'ed maximum should be at least 6-sigma away from the process mean (for the Vi_cm where the part fails).